# Where are the typecasts in OpenAL?

Tags: java, audio, lwjgl, openal

I was wondering why I cannot use things such as ALint and ALfloat in Java (through LWJGL). There doesn't seem to be any documentation that I can find anywhere on this that isn't related to other languages such as C++. I thought these might be found through AL10.ALint like all of the other functions however I can't seem to find them at all.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Fixed the title so it would be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types you mention are just typedefs to basic types. For java the native types int, float and so on are used. You don't need those types you mentioned.

Comment: Makes sense, I didn't know if I was supposed to be using float buffers or not, I'll stick with what I'm using thanks!